# fetch website with python include j.s css

Tags: python-2.7, httprequest

i'm trying to fetch a whole website include the JavaScript and css file while using python. 
The script get a "GET" request and send back the website (local proxy).

here is my code :

```
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
# Handler for the GET requests
def do_GET(self):
    opener = urllib.FancyURLopener({})
    f = opener.open("http://www.ynet.co.il")
    self.wfile.write(f.read())
    return

try:
    # Create a web server and define the handler to manage the
    # incoming request
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print 'Started httpserver on port ', PORT_NUMBER
    # Wait forever for incoming htto requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
    server.socket.close()
```

The result for this code is only the html is present to the client.

Thanks a lot for the help, i'm Trying to solve that for few days with no result any .

Comment: What is the end goal, here? Are you trying to scrape the web page (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8049520/3001761)?